# ::--webkit-scrollbar design is not working in Chrome version 121.0.6167.86

Tags: google-chrome, browser, scrollbar

The previous scrollbar design worked perfectly, but after the recent Chrome update `--webkit-scrollbar` design is not working. I am trying to hide the scrollbar in an element where I am using `overflow-x: scroll;`, but the default chrome scrollbar is still visible.

```
 .carusel-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    height: fit-content;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }
  }
```

and the main scrollbar design is not working also means `::-webkit-scrollbar` width and `border-radius` of `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`

```
* {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: $primary;

  &::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 8px; }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track { background: $background; }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: $background;
  }
}
```

Comment: it works for me on 121.0.6167.85. Have you tried opening dev tools -> styles and scrolling down 'Pseudo ::scrollbar element' and trying to set display: none etc.? or check if your settings appear there

Answer (score 3):

Chrome 121 added support for `scrollbar-width` and `scrollbar-color`. If you have `scrollbar-width` it will disable the `--webkit-scrollbar` pseudo elements. Additionally `scrollbar-width: thin;` will output a light standard scrollbar (just thinner).
You need to provide two values to `scrollbar-color` (for thumb and track).

You can use `@supports` to avoid blocking the `--webkit-scrollbar` elements.

```css
@supports not selector(::-webkit-scrollbar) {
  * {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: var(--scrollbar-thumb-color)  var(--scrollbar-track-color);
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me, and I have put it below the `webkit` selectors: https://syntackle.com/blog/changes-to-scrollbar-styling-in-chrome-121/

Comment: @MurtuzaaliSurti No you don't have to put it below the webkit selectors. The entire point of this block is that the browser will not read it if the webkit selector is supported, so that makes zero sense, and I just tested it above the webkit selectors, and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Order has limited effect on CSS selectors because specificity takes precedence. Only if two selectors match the same elements and have the same specificity order plays a role.

Answer (score -2):

update to 121.0.6167.140 will fix this problem